# cython extensions using cuda

Tags: cuda, cython, distutils, nvcc

I have a conv net implementation as a C++ class. The class is built on top of a template library ( [mshadow](https://github.com/tqchen/mshadow) ) that generates CUDA code, so it takes the form of a header file. Consequently, it can only be used in files compiled using nvcc. I am now trying to wrap this class in Python for easier loading and saving of parameters, data, etc.

How do I go about wrapping the C++ class using Cython? I looked at [npcuda-example](https://github.com/rmcgibbo/npcuda-example), which demonstrates how to write a wrapper pyx file around a C++ class. Unfortunately, in this example, the pyx file compiles to a cpp file. This will not work for me because I need to include the class header in the pyx file and compile it using nvcc.

I believe I could use the setup.py from npcuda-example if there were some way to force the wrapper pyx file to compile to a cu file so that nvcc would be called when distutils tried to compile the extension.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

in the npcuda-example, the wrapper.pyx will combine *.cu by defining

```
cdef extern from "src/manager.hh"
```

I guess it is exactly what you want?